# Prove using induction $(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_k) \cup B = (A_1 \cup B) \cap (A_2 \cup B) \cap ... (A_k \cup B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Prove that if $A_1, A_2, ... , A_n$ and $B$ are sets, then:
$(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n) \cup B = (A_1 \cup B) \cap (A_2 \cup B) \cap ... \cap (A_n \cup B)$

Here's what I have. Could someone tell me if this is correct, and if not point me in a helpful direction. Thanks!

[image]

P.S. is there a name for that last step? Am I missing some brackets?

Should the last part look like this with braces:
$[[(A_1 \cup B) \cap (A_2 \cup B) \cap ... \cap (A_k \cup B)] \cap (A_{k+1})] \cup B =$

Comment: In the induction step you need the result for $2$ sets. Have you done that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But, I've only done what's on the page.

Comment: He means that the basis step should be proving $(A_1\cap A_2)\cup B=(A_1\cup B)\cap (A_2\cap B)$.

Comment: Ooooooh I see Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what "Assume:  Prove that if..." means (directly after 'Inductive step').

Comment: Whoops I copy pasted too much there, it should just say Assume: if... Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1.(A_1 \cap A_2 ) \cup B = (A_1 \cup B) \cap (A_2 \cup B) $$$$2.(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_{n-1}) \cup B = (A_1 \cup B) \cap (A_2 \cup B) \cap ... \cap (A_{n-1} \cup B)$$ you want prove $$(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n) \cup B = (A_1 \cup B) \cap (A_2 \cup B) \cap ... \cap (A_n \cup B)$$ let$ (A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_{n-1})=c$ then according to induction base $$(c \cap A_n ) \cup B = (c \cup B) \cap (A_n \cup B)$$ then according to  induction hyposis    $$(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n) \cup B = (A_1 \cup B) \cap (A_2 \cup B) \cap ... \cap (A_n \cup B)$$

Comment: So where I screwed up was at the basis step. Is the way I have the brackets set up equivalent to your set c?

Answer (score 1):

$$ (A_1 \cup B) \cap (A_2 \cup B) \cap ... \cap (A_n \cup B)$$
$$\Rightarrow (A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n) \cup B =((A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_{n-1})\cap A_n) \cup B = ((A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_{n-1})\cup B)\cap (A_n\cup B)
$$

Considering $(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_{n-1})=S$ as a new set.

Using Induction Hypothesis we have,
$$(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_{n-1})\cup B=(A_1 \cup B) \cap (A_2 \cup B) \cap ... \cap (A_{n-1} \cup B)$$
$$\Rightarrow (A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n) \cup B=(A_1 \cup B) \cap (A_2 \cup B) \cap ... \cap (A_n \cup B)$$
For the case of $2$ it can be easily shown (eg. using Venn Diagram).